# switch window manager when logging in in text mode

Tags: x11, window-manager

Suppose I don't start the display manager on boot and login through the terminal. How would I switch my window manager? With gdm or gdm3, you use a scroll box to select it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? When logged in to a tty you don't have a window (no s!) manager. So what window manager do you want to change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`startx` and `xinit` take an X client on their command line. This can be the name of a window manager or session manager.

```
startx awesome
```

If you don't pass this argument, then they run the script `~/.xinitrc`, which is responsible for starting your window manager. In the absence of this file, they use some system default.

Answer (score 2):

The Arch Wiki has [an example script](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc#On_the_command_line) that you can include in your `.xinitrc` to choose a particular window manager when you start `X`:

```
# Executed by startx (run your window manager from here)

if [[ $1 == "fluxbox" ]]
then
  exec startfluxbox
elif [[ $1 == "spectrwm" ]]
then
  exec spectrwm
else
  echo "Choose a window manager"
fi
```

You can then simply issue `xinit fluxbox` or `xinit spectrwm` to log into your wm of choice.

If you did want a list of window managers to choose from, you could look at a tool like [CDM](https://github.com/ghost1227/cdm), the console display manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch to GNOME, run

> xinit

while appending

> gnome-session

in ~/.xinitrc file.

If your system supports runlevel 5 then just hit the command

> init 5